# Error in decompose(wmurders) : time series has no or less than 2 periods

Tags: time-series

I am new to R and am trying to learn time series on the wmurder dataset of fpp2 package.  To start with, as I try a classical decomposition I keep getting this error.  There are 55 observations, one for each year. Shouldn't the frequency be 1?  Would someone please tell me how to go about this ? 
Thanks a million

Comment: Please share what you have tries. Will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Annual data does not have seasonality, so you can't do a seasonal decomposition.

Comment: Thank you very much Rob